# I can't find out what I' doing wrong when I'm using react routes and my content is not displaying properly

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, jsx

My content is displaying normally until I add route and switch. After that my content doesn't display and I cant understand why. I downloaded react-route-dom too.

code from App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.js'
import HomeView from './components/HomeView.js'
import AboutView from './components/AboutView.js'
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Switch>
    <Navbar/>
    <Route path="/" exact>
<HomeView/>
</Route>
<Route path="/about" component={AboutView}/>

</Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

code from the components

```
const HomeView = () => {
  return(
    <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeView;
```

```
const AboutView = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AboutView;
```

code from index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Move the `Navbar` outside of the `Switch`.

Comment: okay thank you! that worked